# Magento 1.9.2 : How to remove sub category in the menu bar?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I have a site [PREMIER HOME](http://premierhome.com.pk/) in Magento 1.9.2.

In the top menu bar, I've some parent categories and the child categories in the drop down.

I've deleted 2 sub-categories by going into "manage categories" and they become disappeared but still in my menu bar these categories are showing. As you see in my site "Kitchen" category travel mugs and pets are there but I have removed them. These categories when clicked redirect to a link

http://www.premierhome.com.pk/catalog/category/view/s/travel-mugs/id/2669/.

Also I clear cache but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried reindexing from "Index Management"?

Comment: yes but no luck

Comment: maybe your menu is static ?

Comment: also clear the magento cache and check

Comment: No its not static. When I deactivate any category it remove from menu bar, but `those which I deleted is not removing

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether there is any custom **`module/extension installed for managing the top menu`**. I think there should be some module which is managing the menu from the backend.

Next, if no module is found, then check which **`file`** is being used in the frontend for rendering the menu. It is possible that the **`menu is being rendered statically from the file or static block`**.

If still there is no clue, then try **`changing the theme`** for debugging purpose and check that menu is changed or not.

Try reindexing and removing the cache from the /var/cache folder.

Comment: yes there is a module with name getcommerce menu. but What should I need to do in this module to fix this ??

Comment: I think you may need to remove the sub-menu item from the module also.